# Remove binding in WPF using code

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to use databinding when displaying data in a TextBox. I'm basically doing like:

```
 public void ShowRandomObject(IRandomObject randomObject) {
        Binding binding = new Binding {Source = randomObject, Path = new PropertyPath("Name")};
        txtName.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
    }
```

I can't seem to find a way to unset the binding. I will be calling this method with a lot of different objects but the TextBox will remain the same. Is there a way to remove the previous binding or is this done automatically when I set the new binding?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When available

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(txtName, TextBox.TextProperty)
```

For older SilverLight versions, but not reliable as stated in comments:

```
txtName.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, null);
```

C# 6.0 features enabled

```
this.btnFinish.ClearBinding(ButtonBase.CommandProperty);
```

Comment: I suspected that the previous binding was removed when setting a new since I couldn't find any information on how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work. SetBinding is overloaded and the call becomes ambiguous when null is provided as the second parameter

Comment: @Simon, when the call is ambiguous you can always cast the null value to the desired type to solve the ambiguity ;) IE: (Binding)null

Comment: @Pop, your right that would work however Eds approach below is provided by the framework so obviously preferable

Comment: I get an ArgumentNullException with this solution (but apparently not always)

Comment: Ed's solution is much more trustworthy. I also get an ArgumentNullException.

Answer (score 95):

Alternately:

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(txtName, TextBox.TextProperty)
```

Comment: Visual Basic won't resolve the .SetBinding(..., Nothing) call because both signatures take Reference types (a String, and a BindingBase). I like this better.

Comment: ClearBinding method does not exist in Silverlight 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639219/clear-binding-in-silverlight-remove-data-binding-from-setbinding

Comment: @BobKing cast it (`Nothing`) to the desired type.

Answer (score 19):

How about:

```
this.ClearValue(TextBox.TextProperty);
```

It's much cleaner I think ;)

Comment: The documentation on this method is not very clear.  It reads as if it will just clear the Value, Not the Binding.  But in practice, this appears to be working.

Comment: BindingOperations.ClearBinding() calls this method internally.

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
txtName.Text = txtName.Text;
```

You would have to set the value after clearing it anyways. 
This works in SL4 at least.