# Clear Binding in Silverlight (Remove Data Binding from SetBinding)

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-3.0

How do you Clear/Remove DataBinding in Silverlight?

similar to: [Remove binding in WPF using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186475/remove-binding-in-wpf-using-code)

But the [BindingOperations.ClearBinding()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations_methods(VS.95).aspx) method does not exist in Silverlight 3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The BindingOperations.ClearBinding() method calls ClearValue() internally.

```
public static void ClearBinding(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty dp)
{
    if (target == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
    }
    if (dp == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dp");
    }
    if (IsDataBound(target, dp))
    {
        target.ClearValue(dp);
    }
}
```

via Reflector.