# Removing Bindings in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am looking at this,

[Clear Binding in Silverlight (Remove Data Binding from SetBinding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639219/clear-binding-in-silverlight-remove-data-binding-from-setbinding)

But to clear bindings you have to specify a dependency property.

Is there a way to generically find all the bindings on a DependencyObject and clear them?

Thanks.

Comment: A big problem you have is that the answer in the question you link is not actually removing a binding.  There is no API to remove a binding.

Comment: Sorry Anthony, the comment you are making there doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about iterating over all the static dependency properties (using `Reflection`) of that control's type and resetting bindings on them?

Comment: That would be part of the solution but the trickiest bit is actually removing the binding.

Comment: You already have a `DependenctObject`, you get it's type, list all of its `DependencyProperties` and you call the method in your reference link with these values. That should do it.

Comment: Reflection, isn't that quite slow? Could that become a performance issue if iterating over a complete visual tree and doing that to every item?

Comment: Anyway just thinking out loud. I will give it a go and let you know!