# Custom recycling control factory and RelativeSource trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I've written a simple recycling control factory that is used to create and recycle controls. The idea is simple: the factory takes Func function as a parameter in constructor. Also it has an internal stack of FrameworkElements for recycling. GetControl method of the factory is implemented in obvious way: if there is a control in the stack, return it. In the other case, create a new control.

Imaging a simple situation. My control is just

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" Width="100" Height="30"
        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel},
                             Path=Background}" />
```

There are two StackPanels with different backgrounds: the first is red, the second is green. I add a new control (using the factory) to the first stackpanel. It has a red background. 
I add a control to the second stackpanel. It has a green backgound.
Then I remove the control from the first stackpanel. It's recycled. I add the control to the second StackPanel. But it has a red background! It seems that RelativeSource trigger wasn't updated.

Is the any way to handle the situation?

Comment: I have an idea but I need to see more code. Show us how your add the recycled control to second StackPanel.

Comment: _stackPanel2.Children.Add(RecyclingControlFactory.GetControl())

Comment: and how do you remove the control from old StackPanel?

Comment: var last = _stackPanel1.Children.LastOrDefault();
            if (last != null)
            {
                RecyclingControlFactory.Recycle((FrameworkElement)last);
                _stackPanel1.Children.Remove(last);
            }

Comment: Ok, strange, the control should actually realize that it was disconnected from logical and visualtree or that it was added to. But try clearallbindings on a control before you add it to new StackPanel. Tell me then about your progress. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.clearallbindings.aspx

Comment: I guess that would be a performance problem. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405288/removing-bindings-in-silverlight the only way to clear all bindings in silverlight is to use reflection. The way of manual clearing isn't convenient for me. The example described above is a simple demonstration of a problem we have in production code. It's absolutely impossible to clear all the bindings manually or via reflection. Nevertheless, thanks for your attempt. Any other ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: Upload your complete code on github I would like to see where you got yourself into. :)